# Laravel 5.2 update/insert batch similar to Codeigniter's update_batch/insert_batch()

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, laravel, laravel-5

Does laravel have an update batch functionality similar to Codeigniter?

Codeigniter uses `$this->db->update_batch('mytable', $data, 'title');` to do a batch update. More info could be found [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#updating-data).

But as for laravel's [update](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#updates), it seems that it could only do a single transaction. I feel that this is kind of bad when you have multiple rows to update wherein it will be inside a for loop. Something similar to this:

```
foreach ($rows => $row) {
    DB::table('users')->where('id', $row['row_id'])->update(['votes' => 1]);
}
```

For atleast you get the picture, right?

If you'll look into this code, your database could get knock out pretty much as it keeps on connecting unlike the `update_batch()`, only a single transaction is being throw.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** - it is not clear that the CodeIgniter (CI) method is more efficient than a series of `UPDATE` queries. In addition, the CI method is less clear than a looped series of `UPDATE`s.

It is not correct to say that Laravel "keeps on connecting" - it will open a connection at the start of the request and keep using that connection until the request is finished. I think what you mean to say that you are sending a whole lot of queries to the server.

It is true that doing this:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (1, ...);
INSERT INTO table VALUES (2, ...);
INSERT INTO table VALUES (3, ...);
...
INSERT INTO table VALUES (n, ...);
```

is going to be less efficient than doing this:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (1, ...),
(2, ...),
(3, ...),
...
(n, ...);
```

But this is not a simple `INSERT`. Look at the code generated by the CI library in the link you posted. What we're looking at is the difference in efficiency between:

```
UPDATE table SET value=1 WHERE id=1;
UPDATE table SET value=2 WHERE id=2;
UPDATE table SET value=3 WHERE id=3;
...
UPDATE table SET value=n WHERE id=n;
```

and

```
UPDATE table
SET value = CASE
    WHEN id = 1 THEN 1
    WHEN id = 2 THEN 2
    WHEN id = 3 THEN 3
    ...
    WHEN id = n THEN n
    ELSE value END
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, ..., n);
```

I'm no SQL expert, but I'm not convinced that the second is more efficient than the first. That long chain of `WHEN` clauses is going to be processed by the SQL server - a bunch of short `UPDATE` statements is (in my opinion) going to be more efficient, particularly when you're using an indexed column in the `WHERE` clause.

Finally, looking at the CI documentation, that `update_batch` method makes some assumptions about the structure of the data you pass to it - for example, that the first item in the array is the key for the update statements. That (to me at least) is not going to be clear when you look at your code six months from now.

Comment: Many updates vs. when: I tested this and the answer in my case is that a balance is necessary. The slowest is *not* using WHEN and using WHEN *a lot*. The fastest is using a small number of WHEN (ie small chunks).

Comment: Btw, "going to be more efficient, particularly when you're using an indexed column in the WHERE clause" - this is true in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it will help

```
trait InsertOrUpdate {
static function InsertOrUpdate(array $rows) {
    $table = DB::getTablePrefix().with(new self)->getTable();
    if (empty($table)) {
        return false;
    }
    $maxRowData = DB::table($table)->where('id', DB::raw('(select max(`id`) from ' . $table . ')'))->first();
    if (! empty($maxRowData)) {
        $maxId = $maxRowData->id;
        $result = DB::statement('ALTER TABLE ' . $table . ' AUTO_INCREMENT = ' . $maxId . ';');
    }
    $tableColumns = DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing($table);
    $datetime = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
    if (in_array('created_at', $tableColumns)) {
        foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {
            $rows[$key]['created_at'] = $datetime;
            $rows[$key]['updated_at'] = $datetime;
        }
    }
    $first = reset($rows);
    $columns = implode(',',
        array_map(function($value) {
            return "$value";
        },
        array_keys($first))
    );

    $values = implode(',', array_map(function($row) {
            return '('.implode( ',',
                array_map(function($value) { return '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $value) . '"'; }, $row)
            ).')';
        } , $rows)
    );

    $updates = '';
    if (in_array('updated_at', $tableColumns)) {
        unset($first['created_at']);
        unset($first['updated_at']);
        $first['deleted_at'] = NULL;

        $updateString = '(CASE WHEN ';
        $lastClolumn = count($first);
        $columnNum = 1;
        foreach (array_keys($first) as $column) {
            $updateString .= $column . ' <> VALUES(' . $column . ')';
            if ($columnNum != $lastClolumn) {
                $updateString .= ' OR ';
            }
            $columnNum++;
        }
        $updateString .= ' THEN \'' . $datetime . '\' ELSE `updated_at` END), ';
        $updates .= 'updated_at = ' . $updateString;
    }
    $updates .= implode(',',
        array_map(function($value) {return "$value = VALUES($value)"; } , array_keys($first) )
    );
    $sql = "INSERT INTO {$table}({$columns}) VALUES {$values} ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE {$updates};";
    return DB::statement($sql);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Look into database transactions...

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database#database-transactions

Comment: Transactions is used when you have multiple well, transactions (like update then do an insert/delete, etc). What I am trying to do is have just one update statement that could update multiple rows at the same time.

Comment: looks like you might have to use raw expressions. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database#running-queries